# wampserver configuration - how to enable constants?

Tags: constants, wampserver

In my main php file I use the method define() to set some constants. The idea is to use them to load some user settings and other configuration controls, but when the time to use them comes an error message is displayed like this:

`Notice: Use of undefined constant CONSTANT_NAME - assumed 'CONSTANT_NAME' in (file path) on line X`

For some problems there is a work around, declaring a variable is useful but does not solve all the problems.

Thanks in advance!

PS: I use a settings file too but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the mistake was that `CONSTANT_NAME` was interpreted as a string because of the absence of single or double quotes. A small mistake born only for eagle eyes!

Correct way is: `defined('CONSTANT_NAME');`

Comment: And just to close this post I have to add that if you are using it to redirect to the main page and there is a loop, using '@' before de defined control you will skip the errors!

Answer (score 0):

They do not need any special settings. You just create one like:

```
define('TEST_NAME', 'biotox');
```

and you should be able to call it with:

```
echo TEST_NAME;
```

and the output should be `biotox`. I tested it on my WampServer without a problem.

Comment: On production this problem doesn't exist, but I decided to choose xampp with wampserver on dev after some installation issues on windows 7.
The use of constant is to control if the user enters to a section without permission. In case he doesn't have the system redirect's him to his wellcome page. With wampserver in case defined(CONSTANT_NAME) is false, the redirection causes a loop!

For example,
sheet1.php:
define(CONSTANT_NAME);
sheet2.php:
@defined(CONSTANT_NAME) or header('Location http://domain/sheet1.php');//notice the @ with it I solved the problem of the message error in case false

Comment: So, you are using XAMPP as your testing (localhost) server then?

Comment: After reading this, it actually makes me think you are trying to use constants like a `$_SESSION` var. If `sheet1.php` has your constant and goes to `sheet2.php`, the constant isn't going to be carried over. So, you will get redirected.

Comment: I forgot to add some: sheet1.php:
<code>define("CONSTANT_NAME");
**require_once 'sheet2.php';**
</code>
sheet2.php:
<code>
defined(CONSTANT_NAME) or header('Location: ht tp://domain.com/sheet1.php');
</code>
It does loop!
where says "choose" I may say change, but when I saw the mistake it was too late to edit

Comment: it's a security way to protect the sturcture of your site. If the user enters an invalid url the system will display a 404 file not found error, but if the file exists you can display the same error or redirect to index. Example, a class, a settings file, things that make the bussiness work but alone does nothing.

Comment: When you use `define('CONSTANT_NAME')` but do not give it a value, the constant is not defined. You should actually be getting an error about the `define()` requiring 2 parameters. If `sheet2.php` is included into `sheet1.php` and redirects to `sheet1.php`, that's where you are going to get the loop. The constant will never be set.

Comment: Yes Biotox, you are right. I answered myself. The mistake was other, here I tryed to abbreviate (another mistake but just for this post, not in my code) a little because of the max chars allowed to comment. Regards